# How does the EVM track the operations it performs when tallying up gas cost?

Tags: gas, evm, gas-price

How does the EVM track the operations it performs when tallying up the gas cost of a tx?

For example when a word is pushed to the stack - there is nothing in the solidity code explicitly saying to push a word to the stack. I'm assuming there's some underlying, lower level code that has a "push to stack" callout that triggers the gas counter to add gas or something.

Is this correct? Could anyone point me in a direction where I might be able to find more info?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ethereum Virtual Machine executes the bytecode that is present on the Ethereum blockchain. Each bytecode has a specific gas price that is defined in the consesus specification and can be looked up in the [Ethereum yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (at page 27).

When you write Solidity code then `solc` (the Solidity compiler) will convert this code into [YUL](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/yul.html), an intermediate language, before converting it into evm bytecode.

Note: As gas costs are constantly changing and the yellow paper is not always immediately updated it might make sense to look at a evm implementation for the latest gas costs. E.g [ethereumjs-vm](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/blob/da5919fbf2a50d1dea8040d2250e766dc238dcb8/packages/common/src/hardforks/chainstart.json)

Comment: So when each opcode is executed, there's like a counter that tallies up? Rather than some mechanism that reads the entire execution plan and tallying up before executing?

Comment: Yes, this is how this is implemented by most evms